# C++: char(nextChar); what doess it do

Tags: c++

What does this do: `char(nextChar)`. I have no variable named char. Am I calling the char class constructor here or something?

```
int nextChar;
while ((nextChar == stream.get()) != EOF)
{
    // Convert it to a string for lookup in the symbol table
    string foundChar = "";
    foundChar += char(nextChar);

}
```

Comment: It's a cast. That's quite necessary because the specifics of the type `char` are implementation-defined, and thus you need the cast to get the proper value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It appends `char(nextChar)` to the `std::string` `foundChar` using the overloaded `std::string::operator += (char)` and then discards the string.

`char(nextChar)` is a cast from `int` to `char` (since `nextChar` is declared as `int`) - equivalent to `(char)nextChar`.

Comment: Typecast ofc.. I am used to java doing it like (char) nextChar so didnt see that

Comment: That's not actually typecasting. Afaik. char() is the constructor of a character class. So basically you are creating a new character object, and appending it to foundChar, instead of typecasting with (char)nextChar. They do the same thing though.

Comment: Another way to cast would be `static_cast<char>(nextChar)`. I tend to prefer that, since it's more obvious.

Comment: @Mahi a char is a POD - it isn't a class.

Comment: @Mahi char is not a class - no constructor.

Comment: This syntax is called 'explicit type conversion' and in this form it is equivelent to the coresponding cast expression. See _5.2.3 Explicit type conversion (functional notation) [expr.type.conv]_.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior of this is undefined, since

```
while ((nextChar == stream.get()) != EOF)
```

does not assing `stream.get()` to `nextChar` but instead compares the two values. After that nextChar still holds the memory garbage it did after the (missing) initialization.

Probably it was intended to assign the value and compare it to EOF:

```
while ((nextChar = stream.get()) != EOF)
```

Furthermore `char(nextChar)` is effectively doing the same as the more often used `(char)nextChar`, or even better `static_cast<char>(nextChar)`

BTW:

```
int nextChar;

while ((nextChar = stream.get()) != EOF) { }
```

can safely be shortened to

```
while ((int nextChar = stream.get()) != EOF) { }
```

as long as you don't need `nextChar` outside the loop.

Comment: Just a note on typography: the `<char>` in the `static_cast` got eaten because the code was embedded in `<code>` ... `</code>`. Use back-ticks instead. That's the edit I made to the original text.

Comment: Thank you, didn't know about the back-tick syntax. Was wondering where it was gone.

Comment: `(char)nextChar`, `char(nextChar)`, and `static_cast<char>(nextChar)` all do **exactly** the same thing. They are different notations for an explicit conversion of the object `nextChar` to the type `char`.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax `T(exp)` is a cast and equivalent to `(T)(exp)` (but `T()` correspond to the default constructor and `T(exp1, exp2, ...)` also call the corresponding constructors). This implies that

```
int* ptr;
int i = int(ptr);
```

is allowed (under the same conditions and with the same meaning as `reinterpret_cast<int>(ptr)`), while

```
int j = static_cast<int>(ptr);
int k(ptr);
```

aren't.

Answer (score 0):

char(nextChar) is type casting from int data Type to char data type - equivalent to (char)nextChar

[for more detail goto below link](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/)